# AzureRM Application Gateway Rest API

Tags: ruby, rest, azure, ssl

I am trying to create Azure Application Gateway with SSL certification. I have successfully created it using Azure Power-Shell.

Now I want to create it using Rest APIs so that I can use/call them in my code (ruby). My question is: Is there any Rest API exist to create AzureRM Application Gateway? Because I am not able to find any. I've gone through the following link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt420159.aspx

It has the APIs present for Application Gateway but for classic mode not for RM mode.

Comment: Links can be broken in the future. Please copy-paste the information needed to answer the question into your post.Use the link only as a reference.

Comment: @eirikdaude Thanks for your suggestions. Next time I'll keep these things in mind.

Comment: @HaiderAli The suggestion was that you use the [edit] button now to improve the question so that you might get better answers, not that you defer to a future time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I want to create it using Rest APIs so that I can use/call them in
>   my code (ruby). My question is: Is there any Rest API exist to create
>   AzureRM Application Gateway? Because I am not able to find any

There's a REST API but at this moment it is not documented and hence you are not able to find it. As a workaround, what you could do is run PowerShell Cmdlets with `-Debug` switch. Then you will see the request URL as well as request body sent to create an Application Gateway. You can use that in your ruby code.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That `-Debug` worked like a charm. Now I am able to see all the Rest API that Application Gateway is using. But the only problem I am left with is SSL certificate uploading.
Debugging shows that power-shell has encoded my certificate file **(.pfx)** data to pass it in API. But I don't know what type of encoding it is. I've tried **Base64** encoding to file contents but my result is different from that of power-shell encoding result. Do you have any idea of it?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. Sorry! But taking a wild guess, it could be reading the PFX file contents in a byte array and then converting it in Base64 encoded string. You may want to try that out.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. It works exactly the same way as you have mentioned. File contents are read in byte array and then Base64 encoding is applied on it. Thanks again.